Recheck price range saved in variables by condition
I would like to adapt or expand my PineScript v5 code. Unfortunately, with the current version I get the "Memory exceeded" bug. I have two time units that I retrieve via request.security. I have the same conditions that I check in the times that create an order block. If the condition is met in the higher time unit, this period of time should be checked again in a lower time unit according to the same conditions. I have two variables HigherTFHigh and HigherTFLow where the values are stored after completion.
here is the part to get the values from the lower TF
getTimeframe1mData() =>
    [highTimeframe1, lowTimeframe1, closeTimeframe1] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, inputTimeframe1, [high, low, close])
    [highTimeframe1, lowTimeframe1, closeTimeframe1]

[hTf1, lTf1, cTf1] = getTimeframe1mData()

And here is the part that needs to be checked:
else if lTf1 < BullBoxLow1 and cTf1 > BullBoxHigh1
    BullBoxDraw (bar_index, BullBoxHigh1, lTf1, BullBoxColor1, BoxTransparency, "Bull Up")

If the condition is true, the function is executed and stored in an array.

try new tool (Pine Profiler)[ https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/boost-scripts-with-pine-profiler-44449/ ]

Checking the nested boxes is not possible. I would now like to try a different approach. If the start condition is met, the bar should be recorded in a variable in a lower time unit and at the end the end bar. Is it possible to check this area again according to the conditions?
